# Android - How to extract nested value from JSON string

Tags: java, android, json

This is my String gathered from a JSON file. It is as expected:

```
{
   "catalog":{
      "book":{
         "id":"bk101",
         "author":"Gambardella, Matthew",
         "title":"XML Developer's Guide",
         "genre":"Computer",
         "price":"44.95",
         "publish_date":"2000-10-01",
         "description":"An in-depth look at creating applications with XML."
      }
   }
}
```

Using this String I created a JSONObject..

```
JSONObject jsonBook = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
```

Then I am simply trying to extract some of the parameters seen in the string such as id and author.

```
"id": "bk101"`  `"author": "Gambardella, Matthew"
```

This is my approach..

```
book.setAuthor(jsonBook.getString(Book.AUTHOR));
book.setId(jsonBook.getString(Book.ID));
```

Yet I keep getting errors saying there is no value for id/author whichever one is first. Any ideas?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

That's because `id` and `author` are both inside book, not inside the json root

```
JSONObject jsonBook = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
JSONObject catalogue = jsonBook.getJSONObject("catalog");
JSONObject jbook = catalogue.getJSONObject("book");

book.setAuthor(jbook.getString(Book.AUTHOR));
book.setId(jbook.getString(Book.ID));
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much! Out of interest, I tried first to skip that middle step and I got a similar error, am I right in saying you need to create a JSONObject for each level of the JSON hierarchy?

Comment: @mgibson - those *are* JSON objects (`catalog` and `book`), so yes. You can of course just chain the methods.